# Validate hypotheses from individual questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, survey

A survey was conducted that includes 3 questions related to the same hypothesis that we want to validate. These 3 questions are essentially the same question, formulated in three different ways. They ask if the user prefers A over B (which is our hypothesis) or not.

All these questions showed a tendency in favor of the hypothesis, however, this trend is not significant for all of them.

How can I validate the hypothesis from this information? Since I have at least one question with a significant tendency, can I conclude that the hypothesis is true?

I have seen that the 3 questions can also be analyzed together, however, the tendency obtained in this way is not significant.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tackling the problem the wrong way.

First you have a hypothesis.
Was your hypothesis was that all questions were related to your effect of interest?

If that's true, then the level of significance for this test is the maximum p-value you found.
Therefore it is not significant.

If your question was that at least one question was related to the effect of interest, then this is can be significant if you do the corresponding ANOVA.

If this was what you've done here *"I have seen that the 3 questions can also be analyzed together, however, the tendency obtained in this way is not significant"*, then this is not significant either.

Therefore probably your test was not significant and you cannot reject the null hypothesis

Comment: Hi Firebug, thanks for the quick response. The 3 questions I mentioned are essentially the same question (see edited question). That is why I thought the hypothesis could be accepted given that one of the questions shows a significant trend. Would you say that I still cannot validate the hypothesis?

Comment: I reformulated the question here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/443018/143537). I accepted this answer as it fits with the original question.